# should I persist the daily/weekly bar data

Tags: data, historical-data, tick-data, database

Suppose a small quant group (4 guys) and the tick data is in hand, shall they persist the historical daily/weekly or even smaller scale like hourly/minutes bars data, or just do the on-demand resampling from existing data (minutes from tick, and then resampling to hour/day by minutes)?  Could you please advice based on your experience?

- if yes/no, please shortly explain: beyond what level bar data should be persisted?
- if it depends, please give some best practices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I find aggregates to be of limited use if the query engine is fast at scale. There is also an issue of out-of-order trades. If aggregates are calculated and persisted right after the period rolls over, you would need to re-calculate them in case missing or corrected trades are present in the official exchange Last Sale log which might be released next day.

We recommend to persist end-of-session summaries which include the aggregates for the session, as well as the state of the order book and auction/imbalance statistics. Depending on the exchange you might have two or more sessions, the naming is exchange-specific, for example:

- Pre-market
- Normal
- After-market

or

- Morning
- Day
- Evening

Further breakdown by stage:

- Opening auction call
- Opening auction crossing
- Normal trading
- Closing auction call
- Closing auction crossing
- Closing auction post-crossing trading

In the simplest implementation, a daily Session Summary is equivalent to an End-of-Day statistic, or the Daily aggregate.

Some exchanges publish such end of day/session summaries which is useful to compare against aggregates from tick data to find any data quality issues.